# Why is compiling as Any CPU producing an x86 exe?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, x86, 64-bit

I'm trying to compile a C# program as Any CPU in release mode. I expect the exe being created to be MSIL [processor architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.processorarchitecture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) because of the Any CPU setting. However, it's outputting an x86 one instead (I'm checking using the dotPeek assembly browser to check).

If I specify it to be an x64 program, I will get an x64 program. Likewise for when I specify x86.

I should be getting an MSIL processor architecture because of the Any CPU right? Why is it not happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to un-check `Prefer 32-bit`

```
Properties -> Build -> Prefer 32-bit
```

This is a bit old, yet still relevant

[What AnyCPU Really Means As Of .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/)

> The difference, then, between “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” and “x86” is
>   only this: a .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an
>   ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will
>   run successfully.

Comment: Thanks. Now it produces the MSIL exe successfully. I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes, it's not allowing me just yet.

Comment: New link location: https://dzone.com/articles/what-anycpu-really-means-net